# JavaScript string replace() not working when replacing variable

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace

I'm trying to create a JavaScript script for highlighting certain text on a page. Right now I'm having issues trying to replace text (from the body html) with other text. I want to replace all instances of each item in the array `highlights` with some other text.

The code that I'm using is:

```
    var responseText = server.responseText;
    var highlights = responseText.split("\n");
    var text = document.body.innerHTML;

    for (i in highlights) {
        if (highlights[i].length > 1) {
            var exp = new RegExp(highlights[i], "g");
            console.log(exp);
            console.log(highlights[i]);
            text = text.replace(exp, "XXXXXXXXXXX");
        }
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

Currently, I am getting the correct value printouts for `highlights[i]` and I think I am for the regular expression `exp`; if `highlights[i]` is 'Remember', then the printout I'm getting for `exp` is '/Remember/g' (without the quotation marks) -- but it's not replacing the word 'Remember' on the page. 'And if I replace `highlights[i]` in the `new RegExp()` with simply the string "Remember" it works correctly. Any ideas on what's wrong?

**EDIT:**
I solved the problem! When creating the `RegExp()` I passed in `highlights[i].trim()` instead of just `highlights[i]` to get rid of whitespace at the beginning/end and it appears to be working now.

Comment: Don't use `for ..in` to iterate through arrays, use a regular for loop.

Comment: What is wrong with `/Remember/g` ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour with a live demo? [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: @Musa What's wrong with for...in? Is there any reason why that would be messing up the replace()?

Comment: str.replace will replace only the first element of a string if you do not pass a regular 'Regular expression' :)

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, I wasn't clear. It seems like `/Remember/g` should work correctly, but for some reason it's not replacing the word 'Remember'.

Comment: You know that `i` is global? Maybe it's been affected by other scopes...

Comment: @DavidThomas I just tried JS Fiddle and it seems to still be having the same problem.

Comment: @EnesUnal: But I AM passing it a regular expression...

Comment: @elclanrs I didn't know that `i` is global. But I'm getting the correct printouts, so the `for` loop should be working correctly.

Comment: Can you post a link to your JS Fiddle, so we can see what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problem with your multiline `server.responseText` .
I replaced the input with spaces instead of newlines, and all the replacements work fine :

http://jsfiddle.net/XTdgJ/1/

Comment: Ok, so I called trim() on each line (to clean them up) before creating the regular expression and it appears to be working now. I thought that I'd already tried it earlier, but I guess not.

Comment: @scae newlines are usually hard to detect in console as well !